# A group of order $595$ has a normal subgroup of order $17$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, sylow-theory

I was referring this question, which i understood but the last three lines of Don Antonio's answer -

[A group of order $595$ has a normal Sylow 17-subgroup.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602310/a-group-of-order-595-has-a-normal-sylow-17-subgroup).

Any help with the last three lines-

"But then we're done since $H_7H_{17}$ is a cyclic group with an obviously normal subgroup of order $\;17\;$, and normal subgroup of normal **cyclic** subgroup is normal itself, i.e.

$$A\lhd B\lhd G \text{ and }B\text{ cyclic}\implies A\lhd G."$$

Comment: What is the obvious subgroup of order $17$ in $H_{7}H_{17}$?

Comment: A cyclic group of order $7\cdot 17 = 119$ has an element $g$ of order $119$. $g^7$ has order $17$, and thus generates a (cyclic) subgroup of order $17$. That's the obvious subgroup of order $17$. Alternatively, the identity element along with the $16$ elements of order $17$ (which will turn out to be $g^7, g^{14}, g^{21},$ and so on).

Comment: Wow it's nice, now how is $g^{7}$ normal?

Comment: oh is that $g^{7}$ is a subgroup of a normal subgroup here $H_{7}H_{17}$ ,and hence normal?

Comment: @Arthur why actually we are leaving the trivial elements like the identity elements while calculation of total number of elements like here in the above answer $35*(17 - 1)$?

Comment: Because the identity element has order $1$, not $17$, and because it's the only element where the different order-$17$-groups intersects. That means that for each of the $35$ order-$17$-groups, there are $16$ elements that it has to itself. That makes it $35\cdot 16$ elements of order $17$.

Comment: @Arthur nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

In general you can apply two facts: every subgroup $A$ of a cyclic group $B$ is *characteristic* (that is, being fixed by any automorphism of $B$, and we write $A$ char $B$). Secondly, if $A$ char $B \unlhd G$, then $A \unlhd G$. The proofs of these two statements are straightforward and by the way can be found on this site, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099526/characteristics-subgroups-normal-subgroups-and-the-commutator) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994201/subgroups-of-a-finite-normal-cyclic-group).